# Does a vector bundle need to be considered in an ambient space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

We may consider manifolds without embedding them into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for example.

Is it possible to do the same with vector bundles, or must they always sit inside $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the definition of vector bundles in *any* textbook you will see that they are defined independently of any ambient space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, but you need to work a little.
Start out by letting your manifold have a [differentiable structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure). This enables you to define smooth (differentiable) functions.
Then define the tangent space at a point by using one of your [favourite definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Formal_definitions) - they all give the same result. Note that the tangent space at a point is a highly abstract notion - this is essentially the price you pay for not using an ambient space.
Next you take the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) of all tangent spaces at all points of the manifold and give it a manifold structure by explicitly constructing [coordinate charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#Topology_and_smooth_structure). You then have the so called [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle)

Also note that the tangent bundle is indeed a special case of a (smooth) [vector bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) or more generally a (smooth) [fibre bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle).

Comment: The OP didn't ask about *tangent* bundles.